# Проверка текста на наличие не закрытых HTML тегов

Tags: php, html

Столкнулся с проблемой.
В БД есть куча текста в котором есть html теги. Но там часть тегов не закрыта.
Мне нужно не исправлять, не удалять, а просто находить эти записи.

Смотрел в сторону Tidy, но там необходимо, чтобы он был установлен, а возможности такой не везде есть.

Гугление толком ничего не дало. Либо функции, которые банально проверяют парность тегов, либо еще какие-то "костыли", которые действенного результата не дают.

Кто что может посоветовать в данном случае?

Comment: Вам очень повезло. Потому что у Вас появилась возможность решить и реализовать вариацию вот этого: http://acm.mipt.ru/twiki/bin/view/Cintro/BracketsStructures 
При этом не для интереса, а потому что действительно нужно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути вам нужен простой лексический анализатор.
Алгоритм такой:

1. Находим начало тега
2. Если он открывающий берем имя тега и помещаем его в стек
3. Если закрывающий, снимаем значение имени с вершины стека и сравниваем с именем текущего тега. Если не совпадает или стек был пустым, то мы "нашли запись"
4. Находим конец тега
5. Повторяем пока не кончится текст
6. Если в конце стек не пустой, мы "нашли запись"

Comment: Сейчас по такому принципу и сделал. Я просто думал может есть какие-то готовые классы, где возможности разные есть или иные какие-то решения.